# Min/max dice problem

Tags: probability, dice

> Suppose Anne throws two fair dice and the faces show $4$ and $3$. It is your turn and Anne states that if both dice show a number greater than $4$ and $3$, you will win the game. What is the probability of you winning the game? (i.e. if your outcome is $4$ and $5$ you will win, as the biggest gets paired with the biggest and smallest with the smallest).

By listing the favorable possibilities, we obtain:

$$\begin{aligned}
&(4,5)&\qquad (4,6) &\qquad (5,6) &\qquad (5,5)&\\
&(5,4)&\qquad (6,4) &\qquad (6,5) &\qquad (6,6)&
\end{aligned}$$

so the proability must be $8/36$ or $2/9$. However, I am interested in knowing why the following way does not work.
Let $X_1\sim\text{Unif}\,\{1,6\}$ and $X_2\sim\text{Unif}\,\{1,6\}$. I need

$$\begin{aligned}
P(\max\{X_1,X_2\}>4,\min\{X_1,X_2\}>3)&=P(\max\{X_1,X_2\}>4)P(\min\{X_1,X_2\}>3)\\
&=\left[1-P(\max\{X_1,X_2\}\leq4)\right]P(X_1>3,X_2>3)\\
&=\left[1-P(X_1\leq4,X_2\leq4)\right]P(X_1>3)P(X_2>3)\\
&=\left[1-P(X_1\leq4)P(X_2\leq4)\right]\left[1-P(X_1\leq3)\right]\left[1-P(X_2\leq3)\right]\\
&=\left(1-\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{4}{6}\right)\left(1-\frac36\right)\left(1-\frac36\right)\\
&=\left[1-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2\right]\left(1-\frac36\right)^2=\frac5{36}.
\end{aligned}
$$

What is wrong with this approach?

Another approach I considered is,
$$\begin{aligned}
P(\max\{X_1,X_2\}>4,\min\{X_1,X_2\}>3)&=P(\{X_1>4,X_2>3\}\cup\{X_1>3\,X_2>4\})\\
&=P(\{X_1>4,X_2>3\})+P(\{X_1>3\,X_2>4\})\\ &=P(X_1>4)P(X_2>3)+P(X_1>3)P(X_2>4)\\
&=\frac26\cdot\frac36+\frac36\cdot\frac26=\frac13.
\end{aligned}$$

Why are the above different? Is it not true that $\max\{X_1,X_2\}>4,\min\{X_1,X_2\}>3 \implies \{X_1>4,X_2>3\}\cup\{X_1>3\,X_2>4\}$?

Comment: You imply the two r.v $\max(X_1,X_2)$ and $\min(X_1,X_2)$ are independent. Is that the case ?

Comment: @Flewer47  That is true, they are not independent. What is wrong with my second approach then? Can this problem be done without listing all favorable outcomes?

Comment: For your second approach, the events aren't disjoint, so you have to subtract the probability that both occur, i.e. that $X_1, X_2 > 4$.

Comment: For some apparent reasons, I don't like the word "simple" in the title of this question!

Comment: @Gigili; it's an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is right, but formula you have used only works for two disjoint events. In general, for two events A and B, we have
$$P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first line of your approach. $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ is only true if the events $A$ and $B$ are independent. Here the events $\max\{X_1,X_2\}>4$ and $\min\{X_1,X_2\}>3$ are not independent, since if we know the maximum is small that reduces the range of values the minimum can take.

Similarly in the second approach you use $P(C\cup D)=P(C)+P(D)$. This only works if the events $C$ and $D$ are disjoint, which they are not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$$

[Wikipedia : Conditional_probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability)

So, $P(\max|\min)=\frac89$, and $P(\min)=\frac14$, or, alternatively, $P(\min|\max)=\frac{8}{20}$, and $P(\max)=\frac{20}{36}$.